# Manage Sessions using facebook sdk in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, facebook, session, xamarin

Launches app for the first time, it shows `FBLoginActivity` and if user logged in through facebook, then how to get sessions when user open app for next time?

Answer (score 0):

As I said some times in this part of stackoverflow, I do not have the right answer for this question but I give you a very usefull youtube chain I found some month ago :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jx7ZNZL9dk&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l

You will find all the information you need about Xamarin and Android.

The correct video for you case is this one :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYTe0ZWKAOU&index=65&list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l

I Hope these videos will help you

Comment: I have already gone through that video by JoeRock, it's very helpful but it doesn't show how to manage sessions when user logged in frequently?

Comment: How you mean by frequently? Facebook SDK already manage all this kind of stuff storing some data in the phone